# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type with createStyles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

So I have a stylesheet like below

```
const badgeStyle = createStyles({
  badge: {
    borderRadius: "12px",
    padding: "5px 12px",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontSize: "10px",
    fontWeight: 700,
    lineHeight: 1,
    color: whiteColor,
    textAlign: "center",
    verticalAlign: "baseline",
    display: "inline-block"
  },
  primary: {
    backgroundColor: primaryColor[0]
  },
  warning: {
    backgroundColor: warningColor[0]
  },
  danger: {
    backgroundColor: dangerColor[0]
  },
  success: {
    backgroundColor: successColor[0]
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: infoColor[0]
  },
  rose: {
    backgroundColor: roseColor[0]
  },
  gray: {
    backgroundColor: grayColor[0]
  }
});
```

I import that stylesheet and want you use that line below

import styles from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard-pro-react/components/badgeStyle";

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <span className={classes.badge + " " + classes[color]}>{children}</span>
  );
```

but this statement `classes[color]` gives me below error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Record<"badge" | "gray" | "primary" | "warning" | "danger" | "success" | "info" | "rose", string>'
```

How to use `classes[color]` in typescript ?

Comment: Please let me know if I anwered your question

Answer (score 0):

So a solution here could be something like this:

In your stylesheet file:

```js
const bgColors = {
    primary: primaryColor[0],
    warning: warningColor[0],
    danger: dangerColor[0],
    success: successColor[0],
    info: infoColor[0],
    rose: roseColor[0],
    gray: grayColor[0]
}

export type bgColorKey = keyof typeof bgColors;

interface Props {
    color: bgColorKey;
}

export const badgeStyles = createStyles({
    badge: ({ color }: Props) => ({
        borderRadius: "12px",
        padding: "5px 12px",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        fontSize: "10px",
        fontWeight: 700,
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: whiteColor,
        textAlign: "center",
        verticalAlign: "baseline",
        display: "inline-block",
        backgroundColor: bgColors[color]
    })
});
```

What I did here is to list all the colors mapping in a separate object `bgColors` (which really could take place in an `assets` folder in root folder), that you can access in your stylesheet.

Then you have to declare a type `bgColorKey` which will be used to type the `color` variable in order to index `bgColors`. It's simply a `keyof typeof bgColors` which basically tells typescript "take the type of my object `bgColors` and make a union of all its keys as strings".

The thing to know here is that you can pass props to `useStyles`, in order to make some dynamic styling. So in you `badge` section of your stylesheet, we pass a callback which takes props as parameters, inside those props we have the `color` property from your component (which is of type `bgColorKey` which is the union of `"primary"`, `"warning"`, `"rose"`, and so on).

At that point we simply add `backgroundColor: bgColors[color]` in the `badge` section.

So in your component you may have something like this:

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
    const color: bgColorKey = 'primary';

    const useStyles = makeStyles(badgeStyles);
    const classes = useStyles({ color });

    return (
        <span className={classes.badge}>{children}</span>
    )
}
```

We pass `color` to `useStyles`, and your stylesheet will know which color actually correspond to your `color` variable.

Note that you could get rid of `createStyles` and export `useStyles` directly from your stylesheet file like so :

```js
export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    badge ({ color }: Props) => ({
        // ...
    })
})
```

and import it from your component like so:

```js
import useStyles from './styles.tsx';

// ...

const classes = useStyles({ color });
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem (which was the same for me with usin the Props on makeStyles hook. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111294/how-to-use-theme-and-props-in-makestyles)